# Get HTTP response status message from Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

In the Android Volley library, it enables one to get the status code using the `networkResponse.statusCode` method call. But is there a way to fetch the specific error message returned by the server within the HTTP error call? e.g. if the error code is `403: You are not allowed to perform this request. Please log in again`, how do I extract that message **You are not allowed to perform this request. Please log in again** from the Volley error response? The `networkResponse.data` is always null in those situations.